# Class "Pusher\Pusher" not found Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, pusher-js

[image: VENDOR HERE]

[image: IMAGE HERE]

it says:

> Class "Pusher\Pusher" not found
> /home/SITE_URL/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php#295

How can I fix this message?

already running in local with no error,

Comment: hi, please show what you have been tried, the information is not enough

Comment: Did you run `composer install` on your host?

Comment: Yes, all goods in local i just upload to Github and pull it in, and composer install, then that error came up,

Answer (score 2):

If you ran `composer install` and you still get this error, then you probably just added Pusher to the `composer.json` without running `composer update` afterwards.

Comment: ohh, then i will try it later, maybe that's the problem, it just added to github and i just use composer install to install the pusher, i forgot the composer update ?

Answer (score 0):

if you ran `composer install` and you still get the same error , run `composer dump-autoload`